# Reclassify is not including one value in its range of one class?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, reclassify

Trying to reclassify data into a binary map of 0's for no data (in this case, no flooding) and 1's for any level of data (flooding). Range for 1's is about 0-85 feet. and 0's are NO DATA.

[image]

But, when I do the reclassification, the output is 3 classes - 0, 1, and 85. The 85's are 4 pixels with a value of 85. I don't understand why this is a separate class, when it is within the range for 1 (0.335534 - 85.22314).

[image]

This only happens sometimes, despite my using the same process again and again. I don't have any exclusions listed in the classify box.

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: Can you also provide a screen shot of your attribute tables showing the data range?

Answer (score 1):

One **possibility** is that your range in `Old Values` does not include all pixel values. For example, if you have a pixel value of `85.49`, it will be rounded off to integer `85` as the output raster will always be of integer type according to [documentation](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/reclassify.htm).

Also according to the documentation above

> The input raster must have valid statistics. If the statistics do not
>   exist, they can be created ...

The documentation then described a set of rules by which ArcGIS comes up with a remap table, which could be missing some pixel values in figuring out the range. According to [this thread in GeoNet](https://geonet.esri.com/thread/81447), for example:

> Apparently, the default behavior of ArcGIS is to calculate raster
>   histograms quickly using some unspecified subset of the data (even
>   though it says that the sampling pattern for GRID files is to use all
>   the data/no skipping!). You can force the program to consider all of
>   the unique data values using the instructions contained here:
>   http://resources.arcgis.com/content/kbase?fa=articleShow&d=35443